# How can I store multiple elements in a Rust HashMap for the same key?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, rust, multimap

I have a `HashMap<u32, Sender>`. `Sender` is a open connection object and the key is a user id. Each user can connect from multiple devices. I need to store all possible open connections for the same user id. After this I can iterate and send messages to all open connections for same user.

The above `HashMap` only stores each user id and connection once. I need to get one key with multiple values. How can I make the value into a list or an array, so I can see which connections exist and send to them all?

I am not talking about different value types, like enums. I am talking about the same type values but more than one. Maybe `HashMap` is not designed for this?

Alternative ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: That is not a map data structure. You are looking for a multi-value map, or a bag. Have you tried something like `HashMap<u32, Vec<Sender>>`?

Comment: @E_net4, I am bit unfamiliar with Vec. (Very beginner here). I saw them in few tutorial but didn't catch the idea yet. If this is what I mean, Could you please elaborate with sample so I can try on my end? Btw, I should be able to add/remove values too (after set)

Comment: You may start with what's on [The Rust Programming Language (chapter 8)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch08-01-vectors.html#storing-lists-of-values-with-vectors), as it covers the usage of `Vec` to store lists of values pretty well. There is no multi-valued map collection type in the standard library, likely because it can be implemented by combining a map with a vector or set.

Comment: Working on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To do this with a `HashMap` you should use a `Vec` as the values, so that each key can point to multiple `Sender`s. The type then would be `HashMap<u32, Vec<Sender>>`.

Using this structure, just using `insert()` can get clunky when you need to mutate the values like this, but instead you can use the `Entry` API for retrieving and updating records in one go. For example:

```
let mut hash_map: HashMap<u32, Vec<Sender>> = HashMap::new();

hash_map.entry(3)
    // If there's no entry for key 3, create a new Vec and return a mutable ref to it
    .or_default()
    // and insert the item onto the Vec
    .push(sender);
```

---

You could also use the [`multimap` crate](https://crates.io/crates/multimap), which does something similar under the hood, but adds a layer of abstraction. You might find it easier to work with:

```
let mut multi_map = MultiMap::new();

multi_map.insert(3, sender_1);
multi_map.insert(3, sender_2);
```

The method `multi_map.get(key)` will the first value with that key, while `multi_map.get_vec(key)` will retrieve all of them.

Comment: Thank you for both samples. May I ask how do you delete a specifc Vec (lets say i want to remove one of the vec's but not whole entry.) I cannot find proper remove for values

Comment: @Pratha In both cases, the method is named the same. Just do  `my_map.remove(key)`.

Comment: But this removes key with all values. Am I right? I would like to keep key and values but remove one of its values.

Comment: @Pratha Ok, you don't want to remove the Vec, but just an element of it? In the code above, `.entry(key).or_insert_with(Vec::new)` gives you a mutable reference to a `Vec`. If you chose to use `MultiMap` then `.get_vec_mut(key)` will give you the same thing. In both cases you'll have a mutable Vec reference so you can use any of the [Vec methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#methods) to do what you need. If you're still having problems, I suggest you spend a bit of time familiarising yourself with `Vec`, and possibly ask a new question if you really get stuck.

Comment: Exactly. This will work. You explained very well thank you again. I will definitely do some learning on Vec.